# python3 - import dataframe from textfile format head1=value|head2=value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, import, logfile

I looked into the pandas documentation and there are several options to import data into a pandas dataframe. The common way seems to be importing a csv file, when it comes to importing textfiles.

The data I would like to use are logfiles formatted like this:

```
timestamp=2018-09-08T11:11:58.362028|head1=value|head2=value|head3=value
timestamp=2018-09-08T11:15:25.860244|head1=value|head2=value|head3=value
```

I only need some of these elements imported into the data timeframe, lets say timestamp, head1 and head3.

In a csv notation the dataframe would look like this:

```
timestamp;head1;head3
logfile row1 - value of timestamp; value of head1; value of head3
logfile row2 - value of timestamp; value of head1; value of head3
logfile row3 - value of timestamp; value of head1; value of head3
```

I could write a csv file using this data, to import it afterwords. But is there a pandas function or a direct way to import these data into a pandas dataframe?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: thank you for your question! The output should be a pandas dataframe, so that I can work with that data in a matrix and e.g. plot it. 

pandas dataframe: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html

Comment: i know you need a dataframe, how do you want it to look like? Can you post how your dataframe should look likr?

Comment: thanks, the format should be, that each line in the logfile is a row in the dataframe and the values of timestamp, head1 and head3 are the columns in the dataframe - so everything between equal sign and pipe.

Comment: can you edit your question and include that in your question? Just write that the expected output should look like.. then give a TABLE that depicts what you have in mind, how your dataframe should look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd parse and process the file like this:

```
with open('file.csv', 'r') as fh:
  df = pd.DataFrame([dict(x.split('=') for x in l.strip().split('|')) for l in fh])
  df = df[['timestamp', 'head1', 'head3']]

df

                    timestamp  head1  head3
0  2018-09-08T11:11:58.362028  value  value
1  2018-09-08T11:15:25.860244  value  value
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I used this solution, so that I can filter just a few of the data during the import

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
 columns = ['timestamp','head1','head2','head3']
 pd.read_csv(your_file.csv,sep='|',names = columns).drop('head2',1).replace('.*=','',regex=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the great solutions! I used the solution provided but filtered the needed rows already during import, so that other different structured elements in the logfile do not bother:

```
import pandas as pd
with open('logfile.txt', 'r') as fh:
  df = pd.DataFrame([dict(x.split('=') for x in l.strip().split('|') if x.find("timestamp") > -1 or x.find("head1") > -1 or x.find("head3") > -1) for l in fh])
```